# Zsh function with argument stopped working with AppleScript

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, zsh

I have a function in my `~/.zshrc` that runs an AppleScript like so

```
qapp() {
    osascript -e 'quit app "$1"'
}
```

This function would kill an app in terminal by using it like so `$ qapp Messages` to quit the *Messages* app. I am trying to figure out why this all of a sudden stopped working as in it no longer quits the application, no error message comes up or anything. The only thing I did after testing it was I committed the file and pushed it to my remote repo. When I add an `echo $1` in the function, it prints the expected argument. I have no clue how this happened or why the script wouldn't actually quit the app. If I run that command from the command line, it works. I am running macOS 11.3.1 and I have tested another function that uses AppleScript to empty the trash and it works fine.

Could this be an issue with my `$PATH`? I pasted it below just in case.

`/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: Your $1 won't be substituted, because it is inside single quotes.  You could do a `osascript -e 'quit app "'$1'"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
qapp() {
    osascript -e "quit app \"$1\""
}
```

---

Note: In `'quit app "$1"'` as in your OP, `$1` does not get expanded as it's wrapped in *single-quotes*.